# Calculating the time complexity of an arithmetic progression

Tags: time-complexity, arithmetic

Can someone help me calculate the time complexity of the algorithm?

I have an array and I want to check if it's sorted or not I start in the middle of it and I check the numbers first to the right and after that, I check it to the left.

I check it with a variable and that variable increases by 1 every time so it starts with 1 for the right and 1 for the left then 2 then 3, until I reach the end in both ways.

So that's why I thought its an arithmetic progression but I am not sure how to calculate it, and what formula to use.

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm; can you try describing it in pseudocode instead?

Comment: Sound likes O(n) for me. For an array of length with size N, you will have to iterate at worst O(n/2) times with the requirement of random access.